# Why does rotation of an image using cv2.getRotationMatrix2D and cv2.warpAffine return a zero matrix

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-rotation

I am a beginner to cv2 library. I was using cv2 library in python 3.7 for rotation of an image. This is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("messi.jpg")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
(cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

# grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
# angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
# (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), 10, 1.0)
cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

# compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

# adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

# perform the actual rotation and return the image
image = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (nW, nH))
```

This code returns a zero matrix. Can anyone please help me debug this and tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code seems okay and worked for me, but you don't show your image...

the output of the rotation matrix is:

```
[[ 0.98480775  0.17364818 -0.25563765]
 [-0.17364818  0.98480775 99.97181918]]
```

in opencv you have to handle the waitKey
try to at these at the end, it pause cv2 until escape is pressed..

```
cv2.imshow("image", image)

while True:
    keyboard = cv2.waitKey(2320)
    if keyboard == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```